# Swift & xcode 6 beta?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm very interested in getting my hands on the new xcode 6 beta as I've been programming in Obj-C for quite a while, but xcode 5 doesn't support Swift, so is there any way I can get my hands on xcode 6 beta? I'm not a developer on Apple since I've just been coding back and forth by myself.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have developer account at Apple you can not get.

Answer (score 4):

No, unfortunately it's not possible. You need to have a paid membership:

[image]

Xcode 6 is currently in beta, it will be available for free when the stable version is released.

Comment: Actually you dont need to be part of the Mac Dev program because I'm only part of the iOS dev program and they had Yosemite to download for us.

Comment: @JacobBanks That warning is just illustration. It doesn't matter whether the paid membership is for a Mac or iOS Developer Program.

Comment: I understand I'm just correcting that warning haha, It says they must be part of the Mac Developer program

Comment: You can also get Yosemite beta if you sign up for the [beta program](https://appleseed.apple.com/sp/betaprogram), I believe, but the real question is, "Will that get you Xcode 6?"

Comment: @Sortofabeginner i hope not haha, but i don't think so